# Uri is returning AbsolutePath not AbsoluteUri

Tags: mfc, c++-cli, download

Right now I'm trying to download the page source of a certain HTML website. I'm attempting to stay with in default the libraries so I'm using DownloadFileAsync. The Uri I pass DownloadFileAsync gets stored under the AbsoluteUri setting I guess you could call it, but when DownloadFileAsync is called it uses the AbsolutePath of teh Uri which I have no idea how to set and is automatically set as the websites index page which is not what I want. So I would like to know how to change either change the AbsolutePath or use the AbsoluteUri as the url DownloadFileAsync uses. Also like I said I'd like to stay with default libraries but if someone can honestly recommend a good simple external library I'll give it a shot.

Code

```
void Downloader::GetHTML(CString HTML)
{
string Temp, Data="";
WebClient^ myClient = gcnew WebClient;   
    WebProxy wProxy;
    myClient->Proxy = wProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
myClient->Credentials = CredentialCache::DefaultCredentials;

String^ HTML = gcnew String (GetSourceHTML(HTML));
Uri^ Base = gcnew Uri("http://walmart.com");
Uri^ Link = gcnew Uri(Base,HTML);

myClient->DownloadFileAsync(Link,"C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Test2.txt");


}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? you do a recursion call using the same html

Comment: @Vlad L Sorry made a mistake when adding my code. Essentially my problem is that i have http://www.walmart.com as my base url I then receive a path lets say /electronics.htm or something, that is assigned the the String^ HTML variable. So the full Url should be http://www.walmart.com/electronics.htm with the absoultePath of the uri being /electronics.htm. Instead the absolutePath is just "/" and I'm not sure why

Comment: but still, why recursion? and how do you want to use two HTML of different type in one scope? modify the code, I think I can help you

Comment: I guess now I'm not really sure what your looking for ha. I understand recursion as calling the same function within itself but that may be wrong which is why I'm confused as to what you mean by recursion. The second half of the URL is acquired by another function based on what the the user wants so the full URL is not definitive at the start. This is why i call GetSourceHTML() and why my URI Link contains the Base Uri and the HTML system string. I'll modify the code I just need to know what to modify or what your looking for I guess, don't know if that helps...

Comment: you had GetHTML instead of GetSourceHTML before the edit. Were you able to see the values of BASE and HTML in debugger?

Comment: yea their values are what I expect them to be but for whatever reason the value of HTML isn't getting assigned to AbsolutePath

Comment: I've just tried to open http://www.walmart.com/electronics.htm in browser but the page doesn't exist. Auto redirection would redirect me to http://www.walmart.com/index.gsp. so maybe you are just passing the wrong values?

Comment: Sorry I made that path up off the top of my head. I know for fact the paths are right because I've copied them directly from my browser will viewing that part of the site. I was hoping for a way to maybe manually assign the path to the AbsoluteProperty